# Excel VBA - Checking a Sequence of Numbers and Replacing Next or Last Value if Necessary

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an extreme difficulty trying to solve this problem.  I've tried using case statements and if/else statements with no luck.  Here is my problem!  I have a sequence of numbers in one column such as 42,43,49,50 where 42 is always followed with the value 43 and where 49 is always followed with a value of 50.

Sometimes I have a sequence of numbers where they are out of order such as 42,43,49,43.  In this case I need to change the pattern to 42,43,49,50.
In another case I have a sequence of numbers such as 42,50,49,50 where I need to change the pattern to 49,50,49,50.

Here is my logic:  1st case...  If cell = 50 go back to last cell and if that cell = 43 change that cell value to a 49.  2nd case...  If cell = 49 go to next available cell and if that cell = 43 change that value to a 50.  Keep in mind there are going to be empty cells that have to be dealt with like in the following column.

A
42
"empty"
43
"empty"
49
"empty"
"empty"
"empty"
43

Let me know if you all need more clarification and thank you for looking and helping!  I hope I followed the question format and sorry if I did not!

Thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: Loop backwards through the cells: if you find a 50 then set the next number found to 49.  If you find a 43 then set the next one to 42.

Comment: Thank you for replying and helping.  I'm kind of new VBA and I'm not sure how to do this.  I've been searching how to reverse loop using something on the lines of the following:                    'Dim CELL As Range
Dim TotalRows As Long
TotalRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = TotalRows To 1 Step -1
    Set c = Range("A" & i)
        If c.CELL.Value = 50 Then
        c.CELL.Value = 49
Next i'

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I can't get the code formatting to work in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
Sub Tester()

Dim c As Range, i As Long, vLast

    Set c = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    Do While c.Row >= 2
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(vLast) > 0 Then
                If vLast = 50 Then c.Value = 49
                If vLast = 43 Then c.Value = 42
            End If
            vLast = c.Value
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and reply again! It's giving me an "application-defined or object-defined error at Set c = c.offset (-1, 0)  Also, it looks like from your code you're not taking into account 49, 43 scenario which should be 49,50.  So, to fix this scenario I just need to reverse your code.  Instead of going xlup the rows I should go xldown and increment by (1, 0).  Again, I appreciate your help very much!